# Soft Credit Bug

Tags: soft-credit

A contribution containing a Soft Credit appears to not be reflecting the PayPal fee that was recorded for that contribution. Other contributions are correctly showing Total-Fee=Net amounts. This contribution displaying the bug appears to be ignoring the Fee amount so that Total-Fee=Total. ($100 total amount - $3 fee = $100 Net amount) Civi version 4.7.13